# Is Polymorphism accompanied with an energy change?

Tags: energy, crystal-structure, differential-scanning-calorimetry

Differential Scanning Colorimetry (DSC) is a technique used to identify Polymorphism by revealing two melting points of a pure crystalline structure.

DSC shows a peak associated with the formation of the crystals. Hot Stage Microscopy (HSM) shows that only one of the polymorphs forms at the crystallisation temperature, the second polymorph forms between the crystallisation temperature and the melting temperatures.

Is the formation of the second polymorph not accompanied with a change in energy? If not, then why would the two structures have a different melting point seeing as no energy has entered or exited the system?